# Scene from a TV show with two men talking and one of them summarising Star Wars in a funny way

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

A while ago I watched a scene from a TV show on YT. The title of the show was provided, but unfortunately I don't remember it. I think the show was British, but I'm not sure.

The scene was around 1-2 minutes long and involved two men sitting in a restaurant/pub and talking. One man was significantly older than the other.

The older man was explaining something to the younger man. I think it involved some criminal activity, perhaps they were gangsters. During the conversation he said something like "You know, it's like in your favourite movie". The younger man asked what movie and the older one summarised the plot of *Star Wars* series in a very funny way. He was saying things like: "the movie where this guy falls in love in his sister and his father becomes a robot", etc.

Comment: This question reminds me of the famous summary of The Wizard of Oz: *Transported to a surreal landscape, a young girl kills the first woman she meets and then teams up with three complete strangers to kill again.*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[The Thick of It](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thick_of_It), season 4, episode 2. Malcolm tries to describe it to Oliver with hilarious results.

> Malcolm: What's that film that you love? What film? The one about the f&$%ing hairdresser, the space hairdresser and the cowboy. The guy, he's got a tinfoil pal and a pedal bin. His father's a robot and he's f&$%ing f&$%ed his sister. LEGO, they're all made of f&$%ing LEGO.
>
> Ollie: Star Wars?
>
> Malcolm: That's the one, right.

Here's the clip:

Comment: I'm in the US, where sensors are pretty uptight.  This is obviously a UK show.  Do they show this stuff during the day, with that language in it?

Comment: @JohnnyBones in the evening. One reference they make to the differences in such attitudes in the movie-length spin-off "In the Loop" is where this character's opposite number in the US tends to say "Eff-star-star-star" out loud and Tucker is trying to curtail his swearing to match the cultural norms, but later calls him "you fucki—sorry, you eff-star-star-cunt".

Comment: Starring none other than Peter Capaldi of current Doctor Who fame.  I love the description of C-3PO and R2-D2 as the tinfoil guy and the pedal bin.  Do Americans have pedal bins?  Peter Capaldi's character in this show is foul-mouthed, that's a defining characteristic of his character, making it funny that he's now The Doctor.

Comment: @T.Rutter " Do Americans have pedal bins?" - well, we just call them trash cans.

Comment: Yeah but specifically ones where you press a foot pedal and it opens the lid.

Comment: @JohnnyBones This kind of stuff is OK for broadcast only after 9pm in the UK.

Comment: @T.Rutter Yes, they have pedal bins but don't use that phrase.

Answer (score 10):

The Thick of It (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0459159/)
The scene in question